# I am working on a bank data set and i have to use only integer part of 'experience in job' column

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am working on a bank data set and I have to use only the integer part of 'experience in job' column. I had tried this by defining a function with a regular expression and had cast to the integer but instead of integer it is storing address. What I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
def year_converter(x):
    return int(re.search(r'\d+', x).group())    

bank_data['Years in current job'] = bank_data['Years in current job'].apply(lambda x: year_converter)
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMAo6.jpg)[After applying my function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4tcV.jpg)

Comment: Is this Python and Tensorflow? I'd guess it's a problem with one of them, so you should probably add more specific tags than just machine-learning and experts in those might find it.

Answer (score 1):

You passed function as a result of `lambda`, that's why it is a result value in your "after" screenshot.

Execute the function in `lambda`:

```
bank_data['Years in current job'] = bank_data['Years in current job'].apply(
    lambda x: year_converter(x))
```

or pass it directly to `apply` so `apply` executes it properly instead:

```
bank_data['Years in current job'] = bank_data['Years in current job'].apply(
    year_converter)
```

Comment: tried both ways, not working -> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: What is the type of your object `bank_data`?

Comment: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Comment: type(bank_data['Years in current job']) -> pandas.core.series.Series

Comment: type(bank_data['Years in current job'].iloc[0]) -> str

Comment: Thanks - this is what I wanted to know. I must say I have no idea why `re` library throws exception that string is needed while it receives `str` variable. In the worst case you can make sure you're dealing with `str` by adding conversion in your `year_converter` function: `return int(re.search(r'\d+', str(x)).group())`.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your dict in place via update:

```
bank_data.update({k: year_converter(v) for k, v in bank_data.items()})
```

Comment: bank_data['Years in current job'] = bank_data['Years in current job'].update({k: year_converter(v) for k, v in bank_data.items()}

Comment: File "<ipython-input-67-ec442a2a5c88>", line 1
    bank_data['Years in current job'] = bank_data['Years in current job'].update({k: year_converter(v) for k, v in bank_data.items()}
                                                                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: And the equals statement. The update method automatically updates in place. (Like I wrote in my original answer)

Comment: i did what u told, bank_data.update({k: year_converter(v) for k, v in bank_data.items()})

Comment: now getting this:  TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Without seeing the full stack trace, I can only guess - the v in year_converter(v) is not a string or byte.